# Change a single-dimension array into a multi-dimensional array in VBA for Access

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I have code to ask a user for a series of codes that then creates a single-dimensional array like this:

```
Dim strDaysTimes As String
Dim arrDaysTimes() As String

strDaysTimes = InputBox("What days and times do you want to schedule meetings for? (write as 6c,7b)", "Enter Days and Times")

arrDaysTimes() = Split(strDaysTimes, ",")
```

The number of inputs is not defined but the format is. It could be "6c,7b" or "5a,6b,7b".

I want to convert this into a multi-dimensional array that would carry the values like this (one dimension has the number portion and the other has the letter portion):

5   a

6   b

7   b

I know that I need to use a nested For...Next statements to process multidimensional arrays, but I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will help you get there.

The GetDaysAndTimes function will return a Jagged array (i.e. an array of arrays).  This means that to get the Day and Time of Item 3 you would use ArrayName(2)(0) and ArrayName(2)(1) where arrayname is the name of the array you are using (arrayDaysTimes?)

The function SplitAlphaNumString allows users to enter codes such as AB23.

```
Option Explicit

' This function takes the string returned by your input box
Public Function GetDaysAndTimes(ByRef ipString As String) As Variant

    Dim myItems As Variant
    myItems = VBA.Split(ipString, ",")
    
    Dim myDayTimes As Variant
    
    Dim myindex As Long
    For myindex = LBound(myItems) To UBound(myItems)
       myDayTimes(myindex) = SplitAlphaNumString(myItems(myindex))
    Next

    GetDaysAndTimes = myDayTimes
    
End Function

Public Function SplitAlphaNumString(ByVal ipString As String) As Variant

    Dim myindex As Long
    For myindex = 1 To VBA.Len(ipString)
       
        If VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid(ipString, myindex, 1)) < 58 Then
        
            Dim myAlphas As String
            myAlphas = VBA.Mid(ipString, 1, myindex - 1)
            
            Dim myNums As String
            myNums = VBA.Mid(ipString, myindex)
            
            SplitAlphaNumString = Array(myAlphas, myNums)
            Exit Function
            
        End If
        
    Next
            
End Function

Sub Test()

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = SplitAlphaNumString("D5")
    Debug.Print myArray(0), myArray(1)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ReDim`:

```vb
Public Function DivideArray()

    Dim strDaysTimes    As String
    Dim arrDaysTimes()  As String
    Dim DaysTimes()     As String
    Dim Index           As Integer
    
    strDaysTimes = InputBox("What days and times do you want to schedule meetings for? (write as 6c,7b)", "Enter Days and Times")
    
    arrDaysTimes() = Split(strDaysTimes, ",")
    ReDim DaysTimes(UBound(arrDaysTimes) - LBound(arrDaysTimes) + 1, 0 To 1)
    
    For Index = LBound(arrDaysTimes) To UBound(arrDaysTimes)
        DaysTimes(Index, 0) = Left(LTrim(arrDaysTimes(Index)), 1)
        DaysTimes(Index, 1) = Right(RTrim(arrDaysTimes(Index)), 1)
    Next
    
    For Index = LBound(arrDaysTimes) To UBound(arrDaysTimes)
        Debug.Print DaysTimes(Index, 0), DaysTimes(Index, 1)
    Next

End Function
```

Input example:

```
a7, b8, c9
```

Output:

```
a             7
b             8
c             9
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything, so `Public Sub DivideArray` is appropriate. You probably meant  `ReDim DaysTimes(0 To UBound(arrDaysTimes), 0 To 1)` since split produces a zero-based array no matter what. In the second loop, where you're using the limits from the wrong array, you surely wanted to use `For Index = LBound(DaysTimes, 1) To UBound(DaysTimes, 1)` with the 1s optionally, emphasizing that it's not a 1D array.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Try again, please, with no typos. The code is, of course, verified. I've added an example to study.

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, in the second loop, using the limits of the **resulting array**, use `For Index = LBound(DaysTimes, 1) To UBound(DaysTimes, 1)` and additionally inside the loop, instead of your `Debug.Print` line, use `Debug.Print Index, DaysTimes(Index, 0), DaysTimes(Index, 1)` which will clearly show that there is one element (row) too many. This should lead you to the conclusion that `UBound(arrDaysTimes) - LBound(arrDaysTimes) + 1`, returning the number of elements, is wrong. For your sample data, it would calculate `2 - 0 + 1 = 3` i.e. `0 To 3` i.e. `4` elements (rows).

Comment: @VBasic2008: Oh, sorry, I see what you mean. The +1 is a generic way to avoid an error should an array have no elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of the art an alternative to @Gustav 's approach with the bonus that it returns token lengths greater than 1, too.

Furthermore it profits from the fact that the `Val()` function is able to return

- a) the starting numeric value from an input string and
- b) the closing string by a split via the above numeric value as delimiter.

```
Public Function tokenize(ByVal s As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    arr() = Split(Trim(s), ",")
    
    Dim tmp() As String
    ReDim tmp(0 To UBound(arr) - LBound(arr), 0 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Dim num: num = Val(arr(i))
        tmp(i, 0) = num
        tmp(i, 1) = Split(arr(i), num)(1)
    Next
    tokenize = tmp
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub testTokenize()
'0. Get input string (e.g. "6c,7b")
    Dim strDaysTimes As String
    strDaysTimes = InputBox( _
        "What days and times do you want to schedule meetings for? (write as 6c,7b)", _
        "Enter Days and Times", _ 
        "6c,7b")
'1. Call help function
    Dim results As Variant
    results = tokenize(strDaysTimes)    ' << function tokenize()
'2. Show results in VB Editor's immediate window    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
        Debug.Print results(i, 0), results(i, 1) 
    Next
End Sub
```